# How to a center and enlarge a bootstrap dialog in google maps

Tags: html, css

I have a bootstrap dialog that is being displayed in google maps:

[image]

I want to be able to show the dialog at the center of the map as opposed to the top and increase the width and height of it. So far the styling for width is the only thing that appears to take effect. Here is my code:

**HTML, CSS and JS**:

```js
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

```css
    html, body {
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
    }

    #map_canvas {
     height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-backdrop="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog " style="width: 30%" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Test
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a centered Bootstrap 5 Modal!

You have to add the class "modal-dialog-centered" to the "modal-dialog" class.

Here's a picture to make everything a bit more understandable:

[image: modal-dialog-centered]

### Here's the code:

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This modal is centered horizontally and vertically! 
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```